# Apache rewrite rule for optional query parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Even after lengthy perusal, the Apache rewriterule documentation continues to confound me.

Currently I am using the following .htaccess URL rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\.html$ index.php?a=p&p=$1 [nc]
```

This rewrites something like

```
http://www.website.com/thepagename.html
```

into

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?a=p&p=thepagename
```

which works fine.

Now I need to modify this to allow for an **optional** query parameter that may or nay not be tacked on to the original (unrewritten) URL. E.g.:

```
http://www.website.com/thepagename.html?req=login
```

or even

```
http://www.website.com/thepagename.html?req=login&usr=johndoe
```

must be rewritten into:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?a=p&p=thepagename&req=login
```

and

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?a=p&p=thepagename&req=login&user=johndoe
```

respectively, without breaking the original rewrite (i.e. without the optional query parameters tacked onto the unrewritten URL).

Try as I might, I cannot work out the correct syntax. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Tnx!

// FvW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to add ˋQSA` flag  (**Query String Append**)

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\.html$ index.php?a=p&p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

More info (and examples) [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a whirl and let you know what happens!